# Points are plotted twice in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, style

When I do a plot like this

```
ListPlot[
  {Style[{1, 2}, Red],
   Style[{2, 3}, Blue], 
   Style[{3, 4}, Green]}
 ]
```

under the colored points, there are duplicates with automatic Style. Indeed if you set Opacity differently than 1 you will the copy on the background

```
ListPlot[
  {Style[{1, 2}, Red],
   Style[{2, 3}, Blue, AbsolutePointSize[50], Opacity[0.5]],
   Style[{3, 4}, Green]}
 ]
```

[image]

How to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: maybe `lp=ListPlot[{Style[{1, 2}, Red, Opacity[.3], AbsolutePointSize[10]], 
  Style[{2, 3}, Blue, Opacity[.3], AbsolutePointSize[10]], 
  Style[{3, 4}, Green, Opacity[.3], AbsolutePointSize[10]]}]` shows the issue more visibly. And, `plt[[1]]` clearly shows points are duplicated. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Actually, the issue is independent of `Style` wrapper. As  `ListPlot[{{{1, 2}}, {{2, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 4}}, { {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6,   7}}}][[1]]` shows if a sublist contains a single point that point is repeated.

Comment: @kglr Easier to do `Cases[Normal@plt, _Point, Infinity]`, if your plot is called `plt`, and the result is `{Point[{{1., 2.}, {1., 2.}}], Point[{{2., 3.}, {2., 3.}}], 
 Point[{{3., 4.}, {4., 4.}}], Point[{{4., 5.}, {5., 6.}, {6., 7.}}]}`.  Each of the single-point lists is repeated, whereas the multiple-point lists aren't.  Weird.

Comment: weirder yet, check: `ListPlot[{{{1, 2}}, 
   Button[{2, 3},   Print[{2, 3}]], {{3, 4}, {3, 5}}, { {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}}}][[1]]`

Comment: @kglr Weird.  I'm leaning towards classifying this as a bug, I think, but I'm not entirely sure: there could be some reason for this duplication of points in certain edge cases of `ListPlot`?  It'd be nice if we could get some input from *Mathematica* employees.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};

style = {Red, Directive[Opacity[0.2, Blue], AbsolutePointSize[50]], Green};
```

Make each data point a separate list.

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotStyle -> style]
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a kluge that fixes the issue, so +1, but the repeated points are still there: `Cases[Normal@plt, _Point, Infinity]` (where `plt` is the plot) yields `{Point[{{1., 2.}, {1., 2.}}], Point[{{2., 3.}, {2., 3.}}], 
 Point[{{3., 4.}, {3., 4.}}]}`.  It works because it applies the same style to points in the same list, but the processing that goes on under the hood to create repeated points is still there and is weird.